# XNA Game gets more laggy each time it is run

Tags: c#, xna, kinect, lag

I'm currently having a problem with an 3D XNA game/simulator I am developing with the Kinect SDK.
When I open the solution and run it, each time it is run it will get more and more laggy until its almost at a standstill. If I close and reopen the solution it will still be as laggy until I restart the computer.

Any ideas why this might be happening, and what I can do about it? I assumed that when the game is closed, all the resources it's been using would be freed up, therefore giving the same performance each time it's ran.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds very strange. Maybe the game process (or one of its threads) has managed to get into a state that causes it to ignore conventional kill signals. Are you *sure* that previous instances of the game aren't running? Check your process manager. If you use an IDE, check the run list on that too.

Comment: Yeah I've checked that theres definitely no previous instances of the game running. It is very unusual, its usually after 5 or 6 runs that performance starts to take a hit, and the current prototype is being presented to the public in such a way that it is stopped and ran again a lot of times in a single session.

I shall take a look into my code more though, as I am relatively new to XNA and I may stumble across the cause of the problem

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that the game should overwrite some files, as example a list of tiles which gets loaded on the start but the game doesn't overwrite them - the game append the whole list to the existing file - so every time there is more to load.

Would be my theory.

Comment: Hmm, not a bad suggestion, but I'm not reading or writing anything to file so surely I shouldn't have that problem?

I believe it may be a problem with the Kinect code, in particular something to do with the initialization of the Kinect.
I'll have to look into it further to be sure

Comment: Are you calling the stop function of the kinect? In principle that should not be a problem, but give it a try.